# How to create initial Elasticsearch settings when using the river plugin

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am using the river plugin for CouchDB and when I execute the following curl command:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/blog/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "couchdb",
  "couchdb": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5984,
    "db": "blog",
    "filter": null
  },
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "whitespace": {
          "type": "whitespace",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        },
        "ox_edgeNGram": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ox_t_edgeNGram",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "ox_NGram": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ox_t_NGram",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ox_t_edgeNGram": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25,
          "side": "front"
        },
        "ox_t_NGram": {
          "type": "NGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

receive the response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "blog",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1
}
```

The problem I have, is when I want to view the settings in the browser and go to:
`http://localhost:9200/blog/_settings?pretty=true`

The json that is returned is as follows, but I'm expecting information regarding the analyzer etc. that I thought I created.

Returned JSON:

```
{
  "blog": {
    "settings": {
      "index.number_of_shards": "5",
      "index.number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

It should also be noted that when I create a blog index without using the river and run a curl command to input the analysis information, I do receive a response from the browser indicating the settings that I input.

How can I set the default settings of a an index when using the River plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue:

1. Create new Elasticsearch index + mappings etc.
2. Create new Elasticsearch river with the name of the index set to that of the index created in step one.

I found the answer here:

http://groups.google.com/a/elasticsearch.com/group/users/browse_thread/thread/5ebf1556d139d5ac/f17e71e04cac5889?lnk=gst&q=couchDB+river+settings#f17e71e04cac5889

Answer (score 1):

You can try this url `http://localhost:9200/blog/_mapping?pretty=true`
In the response mapping, if the analyzer is not explicitly mentioned, it is then the default analyzer.